# How can I fix a TypeError with DynamoDBDocument.from() when using __mock__ in @aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb.ts?

Tags: aws-sdk, ts-jest

How to mock this code for aws-sdk v3

this.ddbClient = DynamoDBDocument.from(new DynamoDB({ maxAttempts: 3, region: process.env.region, }));

I tried mocking it using **mock**/@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb.ts

import { DynamoDB } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb"; // jest.createMockFromModule("@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb"); jest.createMockFromModule("@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb"); let client = new DynamoDB({}) export class DynamoDBDocument { // constructor() {} get = function (params) { return { promise() { return Promise.resolve({ Items: {siteEfficiency} }); }, }; }; update = function (params) { return { Items: {siteEfficiency} } }; from = function(){} };

But it giving
TypeError: lib_dynamodb_1.DynamoDBDocument.from is not a function